# Read JSON file and sort by name in Python

Tags: python, json

```json
{
    "customer_data": [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "age": 35,
            "email": "johnsmith@gmail.com",
            "phone": "0413-535-124",
            "sales_value": [
                {
                    "year": "2022",
                    "sales_value": 2000.0
                },
                {
                    "year": "2023",
                    "sales_value": 3000.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob Johnson",
            "age": 30,
            "email": "bjohnson@hotmail.com",
            "phone": "0433-515-912",
            "sales_value": [
                {
                    "year": "2022",
                    "sales_value": 2000.0
                },
                {
                    "year": "2023",
                    "sales_value": 3000.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Ann Bell",
            "age": 42,
            "email": "ann@hotmail.com",
            "phone": "0433-515-912",
            "sales_value": [
                {
                    "year": "2022",
                    "sales_value": 2000.0
                },
                {
                    "year": "2023",
                    "sales_value": 3000.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Sony Mart",
            "age": 42,
            "email": "sony@hotmail.com",
            "phone": "0433-515-912",
            "sales_value": [
                {
                    "year": "2022",
                    "sales_value": 5000.0
                },
                {
                    "year": "2023",
                    "sales_value": 3000.0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "gg",
            "age": "grgr",
            "email": "gr",
            "phone": "grg",
            "sales_value": [
                {
                    "year": "2022",
                    "sales_value": 454.0
                },
                {
                    "year": "2023",
                    "sales_value": 4545.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to sort by name and rewrite "customer_data" in Python. pls can you help on this.

I have tried below code but didn't work.

```
    def sort_by_key(self, list):
        return list['name']
    def sort_customer_data(self,updated_customer_data):
        #sorted_list = sorted(updated_customer_data['customer_data'], key=lambda x: x['name'])
        #sorted_dict = dict(sorted(updated_customer_data['customer_data'].items(), key=lambda item: item))
        sorted_list = sorted(updated_customer_data,key=self.sort_by_key)
        print(sorted(updated_customer_data, key=self.sort_by_key))
        return output.write_file(appendFile, sorted_list)
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: Why have you code in comments? Are you randomly trying things? Is your `updated_customer_data` a dict with a "customer_data" key (as depicted at the top), or is it a list (as coded)?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".*py", line 173, in <module>
    sorted_list = output.sort_customer_data(updated_customer_data)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".*.py", line 101, in sort_customer_data
    sorted_list = sorted(updated_customer_data,key=self.sort_by_key)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ".*3.py", line 97, in sort_by_key
    return list['name']
           ~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please update your question with the text of this error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you

```py
sorted_data = sorted(data["customer_data"], key=lambda x: x["name"])
data["customer_data"] = sorted_data
```

Comment: def get_name(self, customer):
       return customer['name']
   
def sort_customer_data(self, list):
            sorted_data = sorted(list['customer_data'], key=self.get_name)
            sorted_cus_data = {'customer_data': sorted_data }
            with open('output.json', "w") as output_file:
                json.dump(sorted_cus_data , output_file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
             return sorted_cus_data 

I have tried above code, it worked properly but when I add a 'name' start with simple letter
eg: anna instead of Anna - sort didn't work

any idea about it?